# Attaching a property to a component in react-route. How could I do this?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, react-component

I am using [aws-amplify-react](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#using-components-from-aws-amplify-react) to set up the authentication process. In one of my file, I export a component returned from `withAuthenticator` as follows (which is later used in the main rendering page):

```
import { ConfirmSignIn,ConfirmSignUp, ForgotPassword, SignIn, VerifyContact, withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';
import Jobs from './job_page';

export default withAuthenticator(Jobs, false, [
    <SignIn/>,
    <ConfirmSignIn/>,
    <VerifyContact/>,
    <ConfirmSignUp/>,
    <ForgotPassword/>
  ]);
```

The [documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#using-components-from-aws-amplify-react) as I have also linked above, attached a property named `federated` to the component returned from the call to `withAuthenticator` as follows:

```
const AppWithAuth = withAuthenticator(App);
ReactDOM.render(<AppWithAuth federated={federated}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But as shown below I use `Route` inside the render method. Due to this, I cannot find a way to attach `federated={federated}` property with the component returned from `withAuthenticator` from the first step.

```
ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/jobs" component={App.Jobs} />
                    <Route path="/editor" component={App.VideoEditor} />
                    <Route path="/" component={App.Login} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

How could I attach a property to a component inside `Route`? I want to attach a property `federated` to the component `App.Login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
<Route path="/" render={() => <App.Login federated={federated} />} />
```

Comment: Is there also a way I could do while calling `withAuthenticator`?

Comment: I guess you can pass options withAuthenticator hoc as withAuthenticator(App, federated = {federated})

Comment: const AppWithAuth = withAuthenticator(App, federated = {federated});
and then use AppWithAuth in render method of route

Comment: If you see the snippet in the question, I have passed 3 parameters to `withAuthenticator`. How could I pass `federated` there?

Comment: Try to add one more prop after your array named federated={federated} in withAuthenticator